# Unable to test electron desktop application on GitHub-Action Workflow "exited with signal SIGABRT"

Tags: node.js, continuous-integration, electron, yaml, github-actions

I have made simple hello world Desktop Application using electron framework.
and it's working locally fine but it's failing GitHub Action CI.

[image]

[link to action](https://github.com/sutharp777/demo/runs/1651439132?check_suite_focus=true)
[link to yaml](https://github.com/sutharp777/demo/blob/main/.github/workflows/node.js.yml)

```yaml
name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [10.x, 12.x, 14.x, 15.x]
        # See supported Node.js release schedule at https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
    - name: getting node js
      run: sudo npm install npm@latest -g
    - name: setting electron globally
      run: npm i electron -g
    - name: running application.
      run: electron .
    - name: all done just checks passed.
      run: echo ci done successfully.
```

I'm getting following error in GitHub action console help me out which command is missing or anything that fixies this issue. I have tried `npm init` also.

```
run electron .
The futex facility returned an unexpected error code./opt/hostedtoolcache/node/10.23.0/x64/lib/node_modules/electron/dist/electron exited with signal SIGABRT
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

please avoid spelling mistakes.
thanks in advance.

Comment: The following might help: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/24211

Comment: This happened for me because the system was headless.
`ELECTRON_ENABLE_LOGGING=true`
`[12515:0918/114238.687472:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(1434)] Unable to open X display.`